# How can I use Jasmine with CucumberJS?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, bdd, cucumberjs

How can I use jasmine with cucumberjs ?

I tried this solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763260/5453732

But I have always this error : TypeError: this.expect(...).toBe is not a function at World. (/myApp/tests/e2e/steps/main.step.js:33:79)

Line 39 :

```
this.expect(element(by.css('[data-el="' + field + '"]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

**app/modules/user/tests/e2e/user.feature**

```
#user.feature

Feature: Login feature
  As a user
  I want authenticate my account

  Scenario: Authentication success
    Given I am on "#/" page
    Given I check if "navbar-menu-user-module" is visible
    Given I wait "3" seconds
```

**/tests/e2e/steps/main.step.js**

```
module.exports = function () {

    this.World = require("../support/world.js").World;

    this.path = '#/';

    this.Given(/^I am on "?([^"]*)"? page$/, function (arg1, callback) {
        browser.get(arg1);
        callback();
    });

    this.Given(/^I wait "?([^"]*)"? seconds$/, function (arg1, callback) {
        browser.sleep(3000);
        callback();
    });

    this.Given(/^I check if "?([^"]*)"? is visible$/, function (field, callback) {
        this.expect(element(by.css('[data-el="' + field + '"]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
        callback();
    });
};
```

**/tests/e2e/support/world.js**

```
var World, chai, chaiAsPromised;
chai = require('chai');
chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

World = function World(callback) {
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    this.expect = chai.expect;
    callback();
}

module.exports.World = World;
```

**protractor.conf.js**

```
/* protractor.conf.js */
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar',

  specs: [
      'app/modules/user/tests/e2e/*.feature'
  ],

  getPageTimeout: 30000,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    version: '',
    platform: 'ANY'
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
      var width = 1024, height = 800;

      browser.get('#/');
      browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
  },

  framework: 'cucumber',

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
        'tests/e2e/steps/main.step.js'
    ],
    format: 'pretty', // or summary
    keepAlive: false
  },

  onCleanUp: function() {}

};
```

and my html :

```
<a data-el="navbar-menu-user-module" href="./#/user">User Module</a>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myApp",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.3.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.3.4",
    ...
    "protractor": "^2.5.1",
    "selenium-server": "^2.48.2",
    "selenium-standalone": "^4.7.0",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^2.48.0",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to remember is that CucumberJS and Jasmine are mutually exclusive. You can only use Jasmine's `expect`'s in conjunction with the Jasmine framework. `toBe()` is a function that is provided by Jasmine's `expect`, which doesn't exist in your framework. That is why you are receiving the error you described.

Since you are using CucumberJS to structure your test you need to use a separate assertion library, the most popular one being `Chai`. You'll need to use a function [provided by `Chai`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) for your assertion. In your case you'll probably want to use the `equal()` function. Also remember that Protractor's `isPresent()` function returns a promise, so you'll want to use the `eventually` chain provided by `chai-as-promised`. All together, the following assertion:

```
this.expect(element(by.css('[data-el="' + field + '"]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

should be changed to:

```
this.expect(element(by.css('[data-el="' + field + '"]')).isPresent()).to.eventually.equal(true);
```

Comment: Thank you !! With this syntax it's ok !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use our jasmine-expect library. We took out the expectation library from Jasmine and released it as a separate module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/xolvio-jasmine-expect