# "Undefined is not a function" at .toBe fucntion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am writing a test to automate a scenario, using PROTRACTOR:

I am getting "Undefined is not a function" at .toBe below is my code: trying to get offset position of an element :

```
this.Then(/^I should have ONLY LOGO available on main page$/, function () { 
    element(by.id('mainPage')).getLocation().then(function (navDivLocation) { 
        var currTop = navDivLocation.y; 
        var currLeft = navDivLocation.x; 

        expect(currLeft).toBe(0); 
        expect(currTop).toBe(0); 
     }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cucumber and Jasmine are [mutually exclusive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763260/771848).

If you are not already, you should use [`Chai`](http://chaijs.com/) assertion library:

```
expect(currLeft).to.equal(0); 
expect(currTop).to.equal(0);
```

---

To assert promises returned by different `Protractor` functions, use [`Chai-as-promised`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised) library - you would be able to pass promises inside the `expect()`. Example:

```
expect(elm.getText()).should.eventually.equal("my text");
```

Comment: thanks for your response.. well I am trying to get x, y position of id "mainPag" --  style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px;" ? tried using above snippet but its not getting...

Comment: @msbyuva okay, what error are you getting now - after using `chain` assertions? Thanks.

Comment: expect(currLeft).to.equal(0); 
expect(currTop).to.equal(0);   expected answer should be 0 and 0 but I am getting 467, 187--- as per HTML    style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px;"

Comment: @msbyuva yeah, that's cause `getLocation()` gives you an absolute location of an element on a page.