# How to debug (protractor) cucumberjs framework 'can not find step definition' problem?

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I have used protractor testing along with cucumberjs framework for a while. I've encountered this 'step definition not found' issue before but it was always a config quick fix until I am playing with this 'cukefarm' library at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cukefarm.

The 'cukefarm' use 'protractor-cucumber-framework' (https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework) which I also played before. So I start following 'cukefarm' readme page and start building a hello world project on top of it.

Here's what I know about running (protractor)/cucumberjs testing in a normal manner:

1. step definition is usually specified in format like below:

> ```
>   cucumberOpts: 
>   {
>     // require step definitions
>     require: [
>       'path/to/step/definitions/**/*.steps.js' 
>     ]
>   }
> ```

2. cucumberjs will try to regex match feature file step with step definition specified in 'cucumberOpts', and if matched, step definition is found
3. I don't think the step definition .js file is compiled/syntx-checked first before usage. I tried to add some scrambled characters in the step definition .js file, but not in the function that's used by feature file, it does not stop test from running.

In my new project 'cukefarm_example', I did the following check:

1. I console log the generated 'cucumberOpts', it points to the correct step definition file path

> ```
>   "cucumberOpts": {
>     "require": [
>       "support/*.js",
>       "step_definitions/*.js"
>     ],
> ```

2. I open the project in IDE that has cucumberjs plugin, and it shows a match between feature file step and step definition .js function

However, i am still getting step definition 'Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:' error.

> Warnings:
>
> 1) Scenario: Add numbers # features/arithmetic.feature:6    ? Given
>   The calculator is open
>          Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:
>
> ```
>      Given('The calculator is open', function () {
>        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
>        return 'pending';
>      });
> ```

Is there a systematic way to examine or debug the cucumberjs loading process to see how it's doing the loading of step definition files and how it's finding the step definition .js based on the feature file step?

I am running out of ideas by just checking the configuration by eyes.

Comment: The issue should be cukefarm not work well with protractor-cucumber. In the `suport/world.js` you import  cukefarm and load page objects which will be refered by step definition file.  I guess step definition file failed to refer page object.  You can minimize your example to include only one page object, step definition file, one step to test cukefarm work well with protractor-cucumber, If not, check cukefarm/protractor/protractor-cucumber versions are compatible.

Comment: @yong i've minimised the structure to 1 feature file with 2 steps. The project has 1 page object anyway. You're saying  'step definition file failed to refer page object', but even so, cucumberjs should not give 'step def not defined' error, it should throw error in running step def when referred page object is not found.

Comment: This could be an issue with regex in your step def file. I tried running your project and it is not able to find the config file. I am new to protractor. could you update the project?

Comment: I meant that it is not able to load the config file. Some error is thrown. `TypeError: Cannot set property 'World' of undefined`